# Any SuperSingular curve or similar with Fp = Fq which is not badly broken unless big field orders are used?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, snarks

AFAIK, SuperSingular curves appear to be broken by MOV:

> A. J. Menezes, T. Okamoto and S. A. Vanstone, "Reducing elliptic curve logarithms to logarithms in a finite field," in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 39, no. 5, pp. 1639-1646, Sept. 1993, doi: 10.1109/18.259647.

I recall that with a big order chosen for the field ie. 1000-2000 bits, it was possible to have secure-enough curves. But the size of the fields makes the curves not appealing for software implementations that require fast primitives.

I know there are many types of SuperSingular curves. And that not all of them imply $Fq=Fp$. But I'd like to know if there's any type of curve that indeed has $Fp = Fq$ and at the same time, is not vulnerable to MOV for $|Fp| = |Fq| \approx 2^{256}$.
If not, it would also be nice to know what's the closest not-broken primitive.

To add some context about the question, in latest Folding Scheme applications like [Nova](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/370) by Setty et.al among others, this curves would eliminate the need of having a cycle of curves to amortize the cost of wrong field arithmetic inside circuits in between folding rounds.
And, instead, with a single curve we could end with one single IVC proof to perform at the end of the folding process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to know if there is a curve over a prime field $\mathbb F_p$ such that the order of the curve group is itself $p$. Such curves are called anomalous curves and they are even weaker than supersingular curves. The works of [Semaev](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/031.pdf), [Smart](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/97/HPL-97-128.pdf), [Sato and Araki](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiM_L6qnrP_AhVChFwKHf6NBYsQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Frikkyo.repo.nii.ac.jp%2F%3Faction%3Drepository_action_common_download%26item_id%3D9910%26item_no%3D1%26attribute_id%3D18%26file_no%3D1&usg=AOvVaw3s03BNFftuoCAEKppGSMr1) give attacks that work in linear time (as opposed to the merely subexponential MOV attack).